# No CORS access even when Cross Origin annotation is there SPRINGBOOT AXIOS

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, axios, cors

I am building a simple social media app. Frontend is using React and backend is Springboot. I am using axios for make http requests. All request paths  work fine but when I try  `/update`  I am getting ***Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8070/api/v1/users/update/' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy:*** even when i have `@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:5173")` in my controller class.
Here is my controller class.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/users")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:5173")
public class UserController {

  private final UserService userService;

  @GetMapping("")
  public List<User> getAllUsers(){
    return userService.getAllUsers();
  }

  @GetMapping("/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<User> getUserById(@PathVariable("id") String id){
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getUserById(id));

  }

  @GetMapping("/login/{email}")
  public ResponseEntity<User> getUserByEmail(@PathVariable("email") String email){
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getUserByEmail(email));
  }

  @PostMapping("/update")
  public ResponseEntity<User> setUserActive(@RequestBody User user){
    System.out.println(user.getId().toHexString());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.setUserActive(user));
  }

  @PostMapping("/register")
  public User registerUser(@RequestBody User user){
    return userService.registerUser(user);
  }


}
```

all request URLs `("/","/{id}","/register","/login/{email}"` work fine except `/update`. What Am I doing wrong?
Here is my axios request.

```
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        `http://localhost:8070/api/v1/users/update/`,
        user,
      );
      console.log("User Set Active.");
      console.log(res);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
```

**PS:** I tried "*" origin and adding methods to @CrossOrigin.

Comment: Ok it is solved. Appearantly you can't put axios URL like this ```http://localhost:8070/api/v1/users/update/``` . I don't understand why but the last ' / ' is causing the error. putting it like ```http://localhost:8070/api/v1/users/update```  solved my issue.

Comment: And if someone can tell me why ```update/``` gives a **CORS** error it will be helpful.

Comment: `/update` and `/update/` are different URLs. The latter is not found and thus has no CORS attached to it.